# Commands color in spring shell 2

Tags: java, spring, command-line-interface, spring-shell

In SPRING SHELL 2 the default *incorrect command* and *error output* colors are red. Is it possible to define custom colors for these purposes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What happens when execution of a command ends up throwing an exception is handled by `ThrowableResultHandler`, whose implementation use `RED` to [display text](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/3f8e8334ba15b74f38a235841f8bee0cf16081cd/spring-shell-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/result/ThrowableResultHandler.java#L58).

If you want to customize this, just override that result handler.

Comment: Thank you! As I understood, another functionality is used in the incorrect command case (before command execution). Am I right?

Comment: Also, is it possible to disable the colorization at all or not?

Comment: Could also provide a small sample of the overrided handler? How is it possible to introduce it to the main program?

Comment: @ebottard, I have the same problem .... how to override `ThrowableResultHandler` ?  
extending of `ThrowableResultHandler` and making it as component results in `Multiple ResultHandlers configured for class java.lang.Throwable`